# Updating database though datagridview after altering table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am having trouble with datatableadapter.update(dataset). Everything is working until i add a new column to database, It will display the new item but when i try to update the value though the dataviewgrid. I get no errors but the data is not saved. Here is the code.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
        this.inventoryTableAdapter.Update(jobDetailsDataSet.Inventory);



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.jobDetailsDataSet.Inventory);  


    }



    private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::FarWest_Program.Properties.Settings.Default.JobDetailsConnectionString);


        try
        {
            string sql;

            sql = "ALTER TABLE Inventory ADD " + txtitem.Text + " VARCHAR (50)";
            this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.jobDetailsDataSet.Inventory);           
            SqlCommand execommand = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            cn.Open();
            execommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("You have Updated The Job Details", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "Please Check to See you only used Numbers", "Only Numbers Allowed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the query executed OK? And provide the updation code as well.

Comment: The update query is done though the DataGridview in Visual studio. I dont see the query but it is done with this code.         this.inventoryTableAdapter.Update(jobDetailsDataSet.Inventory);
all the fields that are original to the table are having no issues updating but the new fields are not saving to database. when i run this code             MessageBox.Show(this.inventoryTableAdapter.Update(jobDetailsDataSet.Inventory).ToString());
it gives me a 1 saying 1 row affected but when i refresh datagrid the field is empty.

Comment: A new row is been inserted with no data.

Comment: this happens after i type something into the new columns value via DataGridview and press button2.

Comment: I want to add a new field to database and Datagridview then be able to add edit delete the values for that new field.